# Replacing the value without splitting the structure

Tags: php

This is some part of my structure, what i want to do is 'd' value is empty so i want to replace 'd' value with value'xky'.Please help me how to replace that value without splitting and constructing the structure.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 1B
            [c] => DEL
            [d] => 
            [e] => 2015-01-08T0555
            [f] => BOM
            [g] => t
            [h] => XYZ
            [i] => 2015-01-08T0815
            [j] => 1C
            [k] => 851
        )

)
```

Note : Why I am telling is if i split this it will cause lot of complications for me since this only a part of the structure. Please help this out.

- After updating it should look like below.

---

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [a] => 1
                [b] => 1B
                [c] => DEL
                [d] => xky
                [e] => 2015-01-08T0555
                [f] => BOM
                [g] => t
                [h] => XYZ
                [i] => 2015-01-08T0815
                [j] => 1C
                [k] => 851
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

`$array[0]->d = 'xky'`